# Where does "is" come from?

Tags: python, python-3.x

We can test if two objects are the same, i.e. share the same memory location:
by `obj1 is obj2`.
 "is" seems not a function from module `builtin`. What is it, and where does it come from?

I seem to see `is` in Python in a Nutshell, but now can't find `is` in [Python in a nutshell](https://books.google.com/books?id=8a-gDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT91&dq=python%20compare%20%20%20is&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2nfnz2J3WAhXl44MKHS-JBn0Q6AEIXjAJ#v=onepage&q=python%20compare%20%20%20is&f=false). Which topic (section or chapter) is `is` likely discussed?

Thanks.

Comment: Look for "identity"

Comment: It's not a function, any more than `==` is a function, or `for`. It's *an operator, so syntax*, just like `+` or `or`.

Comment: Here it is: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8a-gDgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT91&dq=python%20compare%20%20%20is&pg=PT80#v=onepage&q=identity%20test%20operator&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is` is a [*comparison operator*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), it tests if two expressions resolve to the same *identity*, so it is called the [*identity comparison operator*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not):

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for object identity: `x is y` is true if and only if `x` and `y` are the same object. Object identity is determined using the `id()` function. `x is not y` yields the inverse truth value.

So in *Python in a Nutshell*, you find it in the [*Expressions and Operators* section](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8a-gDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT91&dq=python+compare+++is&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false); search for *identity test*.